# SVD with missing values in R

Tags: r, matrix, svd

I am performing a SVD analysis with R, but I have a matrix with structural NA values. Is it possible to obtain a SVD decomposition in this case? Are there alternative solutions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out the SVDmiss function in SpatioTemporal package which does missing value imputation as well as computes the SVD on the imputed matrix. Check this link [SVDmiss Function](http://www.inside-r.org/node/160052)

However, you might want to be wary of the nature of your data and whether missing value imputation makes sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the SVM in R with NA values without succes.
Sometimes they are important in analysis so I usually transform my data as follows:

1. If you have lots of variables try to reduce their number (clustering, lasso, etc...)
2. Transform the remaining predictors like this:

   **- for quantitative variables:**

   ```
      - calculate deciles per predictor (leaving missing obs out)
      - calculate frequency of Y per decile (assuming Y is qualitative)
      - regroup deciles on their Y freq similarity into 2/3/4 groups 
        (you can do this by looking at their plot too)
      - create for each group a new binary variable 
        (X11 = 1 if X1 takes values in the interval ...)
      - calculate Y frequency for missing obs of that predictor
      - join the missing obs category to the variable that has the closest Y freq
   ```

   **- for qualitative variables:**

   ```
      - if you have variables with lots of levels you should do clustering by Y 
        variable
      - for variables with lesser levels, you can calculate Y freq per class
      - regroup the classes like above
      - calculate the same thing for missing obs and attach it to the most similar 
        group of non-missing
      - recode the variable as for numeric case*
   ```

There, now you have a complete database of dummy variables and the chance to perform SVM, neural networks, LASSO, etc...